# Cannot add WebViewer of ActiveReports to an ASP.NET page

Tags: activereports

I installed ActiveReports from their site. The version was labeled as `.NET 2.0  build 5.2.1013.2 (for Visual Studio 2005 and 2008)`. I have an ASP.NET project in VS 2008 which has 2.0 as target framework. I added all the tools in the `DataDynamics` namespace to the toolbox, created a new project, added a new report.

When I drag and drop the WebViewer control to a page in the design view, nothing happens. No mark up is added, no report viewer is displayed on the page. Also I noticed that there are no tags related to DataDynamics components in my `web.config` file. Am I missing some configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the reason. While trying to get this work, I think I installed another version of the package that removed or deactivated my current version. The control I was dropping on the form belonged to the older version that had no assemblies referenced. I removed all installations of ActiveReports, installed the last version and cleaned up the toolbox. I added the latest version of the WebViewer to toolbox and dropped it on the form. It worked.